# Pandas get data in first DataFrame but not in second (equivalent of left join where null in SQL)

Tags: python, pandas

In SQL I do the following to get data that is in the first table, but not in the second table:

```
select a.contactId 
from #t1 a
left join #t2 b 
on a.contactId=b.contactId
where b.contactId is null
```

I tried doing the same in Pandas, but can't seem to get it to work.. I referenced the main comparison doc of [pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html) but wasn't able to mimic desired output. This is what I tried:

```
final_df = pd.merge(t_df1[['contactId']], t_df2.set_index('contactId'), left_on='contactId', right_index=True, how='left').t_df2['contactId'].isna()
```

The final output should be just `contactId` from table `t_df1` (none of `contactId` in `t_df2` should appear).

How would you write it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I will do with `isin`

```
t_df1.loc[~t_df1['contactId'].isin(t_df2['contactId']),:]
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you confirming my understanding of what you did is correct: 1) choose contactId from t_df1 that is in t_df2 2) take contactId in t_df1 for everything that is not in 1)?

Comment: @user8834780 finding the intersection of `contactId` in df1 and df2, then select them out in df1  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: @user8834780 Yw~ :-)

Comment: By the way this was meant to be not in right? like this: t_df1.loc[~t_df1['contactId'].isin(t_df2['contactId']),:]

Comment: The way you wrote it , if I am not mistaken, you take all columns where rows satisfy "any contact id in t_df1 that is also in t_df2". I want the opposite, all rows in t_df1 that are not in t_df2. That's why I added ~ to negate the expression. Am I wrong?